# Как изменить структуру таблицы SEC$USERS в Firebird 3

Tags: sql, firebird

В Firebird 3 есть таблица пользователей

```
CREATE TABLE SEC$USERS (
SEC$USER_NAME    CHAR(31) CHARACTER SET UNICODE_FSS,
SEC$FIRST_NAME   SEC$NAME_PART /* SEC$NAME_PART = VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL */,
SEC$MIDDLE_NAME  SEC$NAME_PART /* SEC$NAME_PART = VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL */,
SEC$LAST_NAME    SEC$NAME_PART /* SEC$NAME_PART = VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL */,
SEC$ACTIVE       BOOLEAN,
SEC$ADMIN        BOOLEAN,
SEC$DESCRIPTION  BLOB SUB_TYPE 1 SEGMENT SIZE 80 CHARACTER SET UNICODE_FSS,
SEC$PLUGIN       CHAR(31) CHARACTER SET UNICODE_FSS);
```

Возможно ли ее изменить ?

Если да то как ?

Мне нужно добавить поля с ИД организацией, отделом и должностью.

Comment: Возможно ли для этого использовать SEC$USER_ATTRIBUTES

Comment: Системные таблицы (равно как и данные в них в обход штатных процедур) менять настоятельно не рекомендуется - сервер не поймёт такой инициативы. Создайте таблицу дополнительных атрибутов, и свяжите её с системной (если сервер позволит).

Comment: Во-первых, системные таблицы в Firebird, начиная с версии 3.0 менять нельзя. Во-вторых, SEC$… - это псевдотаблицы, из изменить тем более не получится. Можно сделать обычную таблицу с первичным ключом USER_NAME CHAR(31)

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант использовать таблицу SEC$USER_ATTRIBUTES

Добавить:

```
ALTER USER user1 SET TAGS (organization='1', department='1', post='1')
```

Удалить:

```
ALTER USER user1 SET TAGS (DROP organization, DROP department, DROP post)
```

Отобразить:

```
SELECT sec$key, sec$value FROM sec$user_attributes WHERE sec$user_name='user1'
```

В сущности эта таблица SEC$USER_ATTRIBUTES , это база данных ключ значение.